# What is the following label specification for M6?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the following label specification for M6?[image: img]

Comment: http://wenku.baidu.com/link?url=zxXtNVEC2F84hBacmxpeHxUCGGklgf9OCNjEnnkVK2rETP11N5n2qZglmGZTxGzIDrR5Vk6mlIwWsY-ifsyXa3eJKwAfMsmQbx8LNbsi7My

Answer (score 8):

热电偶
Thermocouple

型号：BEM 螺钉 / BEM 探针 / BEM 铁氟龙 / 铠装口
Model: BEM screw / BEM probe / BEM Teflon / Armored

分度号
[Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple) (Temperature range)

螺纹：M6 / M6英制 / M8 / M10 / M12
Screw thread: ISO Metric 6 mm (the nominal outer diameter) / [British Standard Whitworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Standard_Whitworth)

长度：1米
Length: 1 meter

测温范围
Working temperature range

Answer (score 0):

The words before M6 is "英制". It means 英国帝国单位制 (British unit system) [Imperial measurement systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_units)

I found it strange that, on the same label, it also checked "一米" which is "one meter" in Metric System.

Answer (score 0):

The large characters on top 热电偶 mean thermocouple. The characters to the left of M6, 螺纹,  mean threading (such as for a screw). The characters to the right of M6, 英制, mean the English (imperial) system.